# How to read pdb format by javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, webos, pdb-palm

I know that it is a databases in Palm OS, as the development is shift to webOS. Is there any third party javascript library to do the work? or it needs to write manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no binary file access on webOS, the system that powers the Palm Pre.  You can access JSON and XML format data that's delivered either with your application as a text file or downloaded from a web site -- in either case, you make a AJAX-style request from your Javascript code to read the data into memory, then write it back out to a local SQLite database.

Because of this, you'll need a web based utility where users could upload their old application-specific PDB files to be made available to the new webOS application.  In addition to the jpilot-db library mentioned before, there's libprc, a C library that comes with the "par" utility, that's good for parsing PDB files, and a PRC/PDB parsing library for python.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for converting old pdb files to something that is usable on the pre or do you actually want to use .pdb files on the pre. In the last case I would seriously advise you to reconsider. The pre supports a number of nice (modern!) data storage options [showcased in this sample application](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1664).

If you just need to read an old .pdb file once for conversion, I don't know about anything in javascript that reads them, but [jpilot-db](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpilot-db/) does it in java.